# Why StartInfo.stuff doesn't work when calling process.start but Process.start works fine in C#

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to uninstall some redistributables from a C# program, so I look through the Program ID values stored in my app.config and then try to run msiexec to uninstall them. If I store the parameters in a ProcessStartInfo object the call doesn't work, but if I call `Process.Start("stuff")` it works fine. Why is that? I want to use ProcessStartInfo so that I have more control over the window that pops up.

This doesn't work:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
int numberOfKeys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count;

for (int i = 0;  i < numberOfKeys; i++)
{
   string[] guid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues(i);
   startInfo.Arguments = "/X " + guid[0] + " /l*vx log" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   var result = process.Start();
}
```

But this does:

```
int numberOfKeys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++)
{
    string[] guid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues(i);
    var result = Process.Start("msiexec.exe", "/X " + guid[0] + " /l*vx log" + i.ToString() + ".txt");
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do you receive any error? Maybe a good idea would be to leave the window visible and check if the execution complains about anything. Also, you can't run multiple installations simultaneously, you should wait to msiexec to end before executing another instance.

Comment: As far as my understanding of _Process.Start_ goes, if the calling thread is no STA, there is another thread launched which will handle the start of the process. So possibly you are overwriting the _ProcessStartInfo_ instance too fast (there is just a reference which is passed on and on so if the execution of the process is delayed (due to launching a new thread in the background), you end up trying to start multiple processes with the same settings).
You can verify this by creating the _ProcessStartInfo_ instance within the loop.

Comment: Process.Start() creates a new Process object.  The first snippet doesn't.  Process is a one-time-use object.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by putting a Sleep(10000) after the call. Thanks for the suggestions!